# Instance of class in a class not working

Tags: c#, class

I got this class where I need to send POST requests with `System.Net.Webclient`. It's working fine as long that I'm using this syntax:

```
using (WebClient wb = new WebClient())
{

}
```

But when I try to define an instance of Webclient in the class, it's not recognizable like this.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class connection
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.??
    }
}
```

Why can't I do it this way? It seems odd. This method is working fine in static void main of cause.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class connection
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        private void SomeMethod(){ Client.[Apply it here]}
    }
}
```

you need some function OR some place to access it. Directly doing what you are trying in the class is not valid

Comment: Thank you, can i just put it on the constructer if i want to make som common settings for the instance of the webClient

Like the User agent